# Can `foldr` and `foldl` be defined in terms of each other?

Tags: haskell, fold, foldable

Can `foldr` and `foldl`   be defined in terms of each other?

Programming in Haskell by Hutton says

> What   do  we  need    to  define  manually?   The     minimal     complete    definition  for     an  instance    of  the
>   `Foldable`  class   is  to  define  either  `foldMap` or    `foldr`,    as  all other   functions   in  the class   can be  derived
>   from    either  of  these   two using   the default definitions and the instance    for lists.

So how can `foldl`   be defined in terms of `foldr`?

Can `foldr` be defined in terms of `foldl`, so that we can define a `Foldable` type by defining `foldl`?

Why is it that in `Foldable`, `fold` is defined in terms of `foldMap` which is defined in terms of `foldr`, while in list foldable, some specializations of `fold` are defined in terms of `foldl` as:

```
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum = foldl max

minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
minimum = foldl min

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = foldl (+) 0

product :: Num a => [a] -> a
product = foldl (*) 1
```

? Can they be rewritten as

```
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
maximum = foldr max

minimum :: Ord a => [a] -> a
minimum = foldr min

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum = foldr (+) 0

product :: Num a => [a] -> a
product = foldr (*) 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr

Answer (score 6):

In general, *neither* `foldr` nor `foldl` can be implemented in terms of each other. The core operation of `Foldable` is `foldMap`, from which all the other operations may be derived. Neither `foldr` nor `foldl` are enough. However, the difference only shines through in the case of infinite or (partially) undefined structures, so there's a tendency to gloss over this fact.

@DamianLattenero has shown the "implementations" of `foldl` and `foldr` in terms of one another:

```
foldl' c = foldr (flip c)
foldr' c = foldl (flip c)
```

But they do not always have the correct behavior. Consider lists. Then, `foldr (:) [] xs = xs` for all `xs :: [a]`. However, `foldr' (:) [] /= xs` for all `xs`, because `foldr' (:) [] xs = foldl (flip (:)) n xs`, and `foldl` (in the case of lists) has to walk the entire spine of the list before it can produce an output. But, if `xs` is infinite, `foldl` *can't* walk the entire infinite list, so `foldr' (:) [] xs` loops forever for infinite `xs`, while `foldr (:) [] xs` just produces `xs`. `foldl' = foldl` as desired, however. Essentially, for `[]`, `foldr` is "natural" and `foldl` is "unnatural". Implementing `foldl` with `foldr` works because you're just losing "naturalness", but implementing `foldr` in terms of `foldl` doesn't work, because you cannot recover that "natural" behavior.

On the flipside, consider

```
data Tsil a = Lin | Snoc (Tsil a) a
-- backwards version of data [a] = [] | (:) a [a]
```

In this case, `foldl` is natural:

```
foldl c n Lin = n
foldl c n (Snoc xs x) = c (foldl c n xs) x
```

And `foldr` is unnatural:

```
foldr c = foldl (flip c)
```

Now, `foldl` has the good, "productive" behavior on infinite/partially undefined `Tsil`s, while `foldr` does not. Implementing `foldr` in terms of `foldl` works (as I just did above), but you cannot implement `foldl` in terms of `foldr`, because you cannot recover that productivity.

`foldMap` avoids this issue. For `[]`:

```
foldMap f [] = mempty
foldMap f (x : xs) = f x <> foldMap f xs
-- foldMap f = foldr (\x r -> f x <> r) mempty
```

And for `Tsil`:

```
foldMap f Lin = mempty
foldMap f (Snoc xs x) = foldMap f xs <> f x
-- foldMap f = foldl (\r x -> r <> f x) mempty
```

Now,

```
instance Semigroup [a] where
  [] <> ys = ys
  (x : xs) <> ys = x : (xs <> ys)
  -- (<>) = (++)
instance Monoid [a] where mempty = []
instance Semigroup (Tsil a) where
  ys <> Lin = ys
  ys <> (Snoc xs x) = Snoc (ys <> xs) x
instance Monoid (Tsil a) where mempty = Lin
```

And we have

```
foldMap (: []) xs = xs -- even for infinite xs
foldMap (Snoc Lin) xs = xs -- even for infinite xs
```

Implementations for `foldl` and `foldr` are actually given in the documentation

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t ) z
foldl f z t = appEndo (getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f) t)) z
```

`f` is used to turn each `a` in the `t a` into a `b -> b` (`Endo b`), and then all the `b -> b`s are composed together (`foldr` does it one way, while `foldl` composes them backwards with `Dual (Endo b)`) and the final `b -> b` is then applied to the initial value `z :: b`.

`foldr` is replaced with `foldl` in specializations `sum`, `minimum`, etc. in the `instance Foldable []`, for performance reasons. The idea is that you can't take the `sum` of an infinite list anyway (this assumption is false, but it's generally true enough), so we don't need `foldr` to handle it. Using `foldl` is, in some cases, more performant than `foldr`, so `foldr` is changed to `foldl`. I would expect, for `Tsil`, that `foldr` is sometimes more performant than `foldl`, and therefore `sum`, `minimum`, etc. can be reimplemented in terms of `foldr`, instead of `fold` in order to get that performance improvement. Note that the documentation says that `sum`, `minimum`, etc. should be equivalent to the forms using `foldMap`/`fold`, but may be less defined, which is exactly what would happen.

---

Bit of an appendix, but I think it's worth noticing that:

```
genFoldr c n [] = n; genFoldr c n (x : xs) = c x (genFoldr c n xs)
instance Foldable [] where
  foldl c = genFoldr (flip c)
  foldr c = foldl (flip c)
-- similarly for Tsil
```

is actually a valid, lawful `Foldable` instance, where *both* `foldr` and `foldl` are unnatural and neither can handle infinite structures (`foldMap` is defaulted in terms of `foldr`, and thus won't handle infinite lists either). In this case, `foldr` and `foldl` can be written in terms of each other (`foldl c = foldr (flip c)`, though it is implemented with `genFoldr`). However, this instance is undesirable, because we would really like a `foldr` that can handle infinite lists, so we instead implement

```
instance Foldable [] where
  foldr = genFoldr
  foldl c = foldr (flip c)
```

where the equality `foldr c = foldl (flip c)` no longer holds.

Comment: Since `foldl'` and `foldr'` are real methods that do something *different*, maybe it would be better to rename those?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a type for which *neither* `foldl` nor `foldr` can be implemented in terms of the other:

```
import Data.Functor.Reverse
import Data.Monoid

data DL a = DL [a] (Reverse [] a)
  deriving Foldable
```

The `Foldable` implementation looks like

```
instance Foldable DL where
  foldMap f (DL front rear) = foldMap f front <> foldMap f rear
```

Inlining the `Foldable` instance for `Reverse []`, and adding the corresponding `foldr` and `foldl`,

```
  foldMap f (DL front rear) = foldMap f front <> getDual (foldMap (Dual . f) (getReverse rear))
  foldr c n (DL xs (Reverse ys)) =
    foldr c (foldl (flip c) n ys) xs
  foldl f b (DL xs (Reverse ys)) =
    foldr (flip f) (foldl f b xs) ys
```

If the front list is infinite, then `foldr` defined using `foldl` won't work. If the rear list is infinite, then `foldl` defined using `foldr` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of lists: `foldl` can be defined in terms of `foldr` but not vice-versa.

```
foldl f a l = foldr (\b e c -> e (f c b)) id l a
```

For other types which implement `Foldable`: the opposite may be true.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit 2:

There is another way also that satisfy (based on [this article](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/fold.pdf)) for `foldl`:

```
foldl f a list = (foldr construct (\acc -> acc) list) a
  where
    construct x r = \acc -> r (f acc x)
```

> Edit 1

Flipping the arguments of the function will not create a same foldr/foldl, meaning this examples does not satisfy the equality of foldr-foldl:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
```

and `foldl` in terms of foldr:

```
foldl' :: Foldable t => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldl' f b = foldr (flip f) b
```

and `foldr`:

```
foldr' :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr' f b = foldl (flip f) b
```

The converse is not true, since foldr may work on infinite lists, which foldl variants never can do. However, for finite lists, foldr can also be written in terms of foldl although losing laziness in the process. (for more check [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foldl_as_foldr))

Ando also not satisfy this examples:

```
foldr (-) 2 [8,10] = 8 - (10 - 2) == 0

foldl (flip (-)) 2 [8,10] = (flip (-) (flip (-) 2 8) 10) == 4
```